# Opencv works with python2.7 but not with python3.5.2

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

i installed opencv as follows for both python2 and python3. However, it's only work with python2 .
when l try with python2`: import cv2` it works but not with python 3.
here is the script of the commands

https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y autoremove


# INSTALL THE DEPENDENCIES

# Build tools:
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake

# GUI (if you want to use GTK instead of Qt, replace 'qt5-default' with 'libgtkglext1-dev' and remove '-DWITH_QT=ON' option in CMake):
sudo apt-get install -y qt5-default libvtk6-dev

# Media I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libwebp-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev libgdal-dev

# Video I/O:
sudo apt-get install -y libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev yasm libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libv4l-dev libxine2-dev

# Parallelism and linear algebra libraries:
sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev

# Python:
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-tk python-numpy python3-dev python3-tk python3-numpy

# Java:
sudo apt-get install -y ant default-jdk

# Documentation:
sudo apt-get install -y doxygen


# INSTALL THE LIBRARY (YOU CAN CHANGE '3.2.0' FOR THE LAST STABLE VERSION)

sudo apt-get install -y unzip wget
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip
unzip 3.2.0.zip
rm 3.2.0.zip
mv opencv-3.2.0 OpenCV
cd OpenCV
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

What's wrong with python3